# Confused about getting the Installed Application list from Registry

Tags: c#, winforms

I am required to get installed program list from registry and display them in the ListView.I am using this code for doing this

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

{

    RegistryKey uninstallKey = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(UninstallPath);
    foreach (var subKey in uninstallKey.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        using (RegistryKey  key=uninstallKey.OpenSubKey(subKey,false))
        {
            ListViewItem lvItem =
                new ListViewItem(key.GetValue("DisplayName") == null
                    ? "********"
                    : key.GetValue("DisplayName").ToString());
            listView1.Items.Add(lvItem);
        }

     }
```

Output is  supposed to look like the first picture on the left.But Its not
[image]

Comment: There are presumably two places in the registry for this kind of information. One place (or one for each user who has installed programs) for the programs that have been installed for the current user only, and one for "all users".

Comment: Instead of getting this information from the registry I'd recommend that you use "Deployment Tools Foundation", which is part of the WiX open source installer component. Try Googling "Deployment Tools Foundation". WiX is here: http://wixtoolset.org/